# File archival using spring integration smb

Tags: spring-integration

I have a use case where I should read the file from windows remote location with the following steps:

1. Read file from windows share location say input folder.
2. Process file and upload to REST service with the content of file.
3. If the call is successful move the remote file to archive folder, archival folder will also be on windows remote share.

I am using spring integration smb. Please help how can I achieve the archival use case.

Thanks,
barvepan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's on the same share, use the `SmbRemoteFileTemplate`'s `rename()` method.

If it's a different share you'll have to copy the file and remove it (you can use the remote file template for that too).

Comment: Hi, thanks for response. I am new to spring integration and still studying/exploring. Could you please guide me on how to get SmbRemoteFileTemplate bean,  any example.  Thanks in advance

Comment: You just need to add it as a bean to your application context - just like any other bean.